# Why is my code is not filtering and still printing everything in the columns rather than what it should be filtering by?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, filtering, spyder

This is my first post on here, so please excuse any errors in my posting.

Here is my code. I am trying to filter and print this data, but when the script runs it prints all of the column headers which is what I don't want. Any tips?

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv("/Users/andrewschaper/Desktop/EQR_Data/EQR_Transactions_1.csv", low_memory=False)
print("Total rows: {0}".format(len(data)))
print(list(data))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sort_values(by=['Filing_Quarter','product_name','time_zone','increment_name'],ascending=[True, True, True, True])

df.filter(items=['RECID', 'transaction_unique_id', 'ferc_tariff_reference', 'contract_service_agreement', 'transaction_unique_identifier', 'transaction_begin_date', 'transaction_end_date', 'trade_date', 'exchange_brokerage_service', 'point_of_delivery_specific_location', 'class_name', 'term_name', 'increment_peaking_name'])

print(df)
```

Comment: No image for me =) You should rewrite your code instead of posting pictures of it, this way we can copy paste it directly ;-)

Comment: I stopped reading at *"Here is an image of my code."* [Why is it bad to post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)?

Comment: @SOCO, I think you have learned an important lesson today: most operations on dataframes generate new dataframes, they don't modify the one you're applying the operation to.

Comment: http://i1181.photobucket.com/albums/x424/muffintop4life/Sort%20and%20Filter%20image_zpsgvmlgc1r.png

Comment: Thank you all for your help thus far.

Answer (score 1):

You should just copy and paste your code here, but I think this will do:

```
# List of columns you want.
items = [x,y,z]

# Print the filtered dataframe.
df[items]
```

Have in mind that `df[items]` only **prints** your filtered dataframe, **it does not drop the other columns**. If that's what you want, then `filtered_df = df[items]`.